# How to Extract float numeric data from a string

Tags: java, json

Hey Guys i am using Google Currency Api to request for currency conversions information.
For example i use  [Google Currency Api](http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?GBP)

to convert 1USD to my local Currency.
The string returned is {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "2 481.38958 Ugandan shillings",error: "",icc: true}
I need java code to extract the 2481.38958 float data type and save it in a float Variable.
Please Help.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Look at Float.parseFloat() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html

Comment: Thanx Dennis......but i don't see any code examples that help me.

Comment: If you can parse out "2481.38958", then `Float.parseFloat("2481.38958");` returns 2481.38958 as a float. The answers appear to be better suited for your purposes though.

Comment: Thank You Dennis, maybe i phrased the question wrong. Please help me with information as to how to parse out the 2481.38 from the whole string.
Thanks again

Comment: I think the answers already explain it better than I can.

Comment: OK thank You alot Dennis.
Appreciate It.

Comment: Using a float for a value like that is going to lose precision. You should use `BigDecimal` for currency handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the value always will be between `rhs:` and a word.

```
String str = "{lhs: \"1 U.S. dollar\",rhs: \"2 481.38958 Ugandan shillings\",error: \"\",icc: true}";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("rhs:\\s.*?([\\d\\s\\.]+)\\s\\w+").matcher(str);
m.find();
float value = Float.parseFloat(m.group(1).replaceAll("[^\\d\\.]", ""));
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: My compiler is highlighting the matcher variable type.
Does it require any library import?

Comment: Yes, `import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;`

Comment: Thank You alot Elias.
You have saved the day..............ur my Clark Kent....(Too Soon?) hehe.THanx

Answer (score 3):

For your input JSON string:

```
{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "2481.38958 Ugandan shillings",error: "",icc: true}
```

Using http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ :

```
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonTxt );        
    String dollarString = json.getFloat( "rhs" );
    float dollars = Float.parseFloat(dollarString.split(" ")[0]);
```

Comment: But My compiler (Eclipse Indigo) is highlighting the JSONSerializer.

Comment: Be sure to download the jar file and ALL dependent jars and make sure they are in your classpath. Jar details on the website.

Comment: My Compiler is Highlighting the JSONSerializer...
Does It require any Import?

Comment: Eclipse will be able to find the classes for you once they are in the project classpath. Use CTRL+SHIFT+M.

Answer (score 0):

This string is at JSON format. There are libs for manipulate this as an object. 
Examples : GSON (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or http://www.json.org/java/

Something like : 
    new JSONObject("{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "2 481.38958 Ugandan shillings",error: "",icc: true}").get("rhs")

And after you have to suppress unit, maybe with a regexp.
And finally... Float.parseFloat("2 481.38958")

Answer (score 0):

If the response always contains the same pattern (with Ugandan shillings text), one possible way of doing it is something like this:

```
package so;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class DemoString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("{lhs: \"1 U.S. dollar\",rhs: \"2 481.38958 Ugandan shillings\",error: \"\",icc: true}") ;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "\"");
        st.nextToken();  //{lhs: 
        st.nextToken();  //1 U.S. dollar
        st.nextToken();  //,rhs: 
        String value = st.nextToken();  //2 481.38958 Ugandan shillings
        String num = value.substring(0, value.indexOf("U"));  // 2 481.38958 
        num = num.replaceAll(" ", "");
        Float fnum = 0f;
        try {
            fnum = Float.parseFloat(num);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        System.out.println("The float number is: " + fnum.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Thank You.
but my Compiler is highlighting the StringTokenizer variable type.
DOes It require any import?

Comment: import java.util.StringTokenizer;
(but is included in the sample code, just copy all of it)